# Wrong operating software. Can I change software?

Tags: macos, ios, photos, file-transfer

My MacBook Air 13” runs on OS X 10.11.6. My iPhone 6 and iPad mini both run on iOS 10.3.1. I cannot connect either one to the MacBook Air to transfer my photos easily.

Can I change to iOS 10.3.1 on my MacBook Air to enable this? If so, HOW?

Comment: Have you considered iTunes...?

Comment: You might also look into [AirDrop](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204144).

Comment: You probably don't want to try to install iOS on your Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Please install [iTunes](https://www.apple.com/itunes/) which is the software used on a computer to sync between iOS devices such as iPhone and iPad mini.

You cannot change the software OS on MacBook Air to iOS. It runs macOS(OS X) only. You should update your MacBook Air to the latest version by using (App Store -> Updates)